# Omnifocus Bookmarklet tweak - Javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail, bookmarklet

Started using omnifocus recently and really like it. I prefer gmail's web interface, so I did some searching for a better way to create an OF task from a gmail message. I came across this on github and it does most of what I need....

https://gist.github.com/1453374

However, the big pain for me is that when you click the bookmarklet, it freezes up your gmail window into a blank page and you cant do anything until you manually refresh gmail which takes extra time. Is there anyway to tweak this so it will keep you on the current message or return you to inbox or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: https://gist.github.com/1855097

Comment: Awesome! That is great. However, now a new hurdle...It makes a new window for the message. Is it possible to close that new window after it creates the OF task as well?

Comment: NICE- he updated it again and the current version works. Thanks so much.